# Getting an unaccept for another user's question

Tags: support, unaccepted-answer, merged-questions

I noticed I got an "unaccept" a couple of days back, but as I did not recall unaccepting anything, I clicked to see what it is about, and noticed I am not even the OP. It is the first time I see this, so I am thinking maybe it is a bug:

[image]

linking to [Calling delete on variable allocated on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack/12513513#12513513)

Comment: One of your question was merged: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12513426/3933332 means the answer, which you accepted on your question was unaccepted and merged with the other question. Not a bug, but also not really clear.

Comment: Ah yes, that explains why I appear to have upvoted such late answers. They got moved from the original question.

Comment: it would be nice if you could keep the rep on a merge..

Comment: I agree with @DanielA.White.  You shouldn't lose rep because your question gets merged with another.

Comment: @DanielA.White - I think it is OK. After all, the question was a duplicate, either a product of no search prior to posting it, or a bad search. I was just surprised for getting an unaccept without actually making one.